# How insert in database using insert query(mysql) in php

Tags: php, mysql

ककखघगघचछजझ़ंंनधथतणढठटपफफबभमयरलवशश्ँत्रत्रक्षससज्ञाइइईउऊ चजझ़ंनधदथतणढठट पबभमययलवशश ँऋत्रक्षहसषर्टाइउए 123455678990१२३४५६७८९० @()"'-/?₹_+×÷¡¿√♀•∆π™℅¶♂♀【】°℃®©★■◆●

how to insert Smiley and text in database using mysql insert query and so on .

I want to use this in Rest api webservice for mobile app.

[image: Just inserted test and smiley and so on.]

Comment: use nvarchar data type

Comment: make the column as utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Alter the column of table or alter the table

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **utf8mb4** character encoding in your mySQL database in order to use smileys and other such content.

> The character set named utf8 uses a maximum of three bytes per
>   character and contains only BMP characters. As of MySQL 5.5.3, the
>   utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character
>   supports supplementary characters.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

You can either set the data type of the column or of the whole database.

Your can use a query something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `text` `text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Below is a step by step guide to make your tasks easier:

**Step 1:** Create a backup http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#backup

**Step 2:** Upgrade the MySQL server http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#upgrade

**Step 3:** Modify databases, tables, and columns http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#databases-tables-columns

**Step 4:** Check the maximum length of columns and index keys http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#column-index-length

**Step 5:** Modify connection, client, and server character sets http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets

**Step 6:** Repair and optimize all tables http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#repair-optimize

Comment: But utf8mb4 can support with Gujarati character ?

Comment: Yes it will, you should give it a try.